# White smoke coming from 2010 Dodge Caravan -- where's it coming from?

Tags: dodge, coolant-leak, caravan

[Pics of engine and underside of hood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onflj.jpg)

My better half was driving her car, a 2010 Dodge Caravan, and noticed some "white smoke" coming from the hood shortly before she got to work. It's an automatic that we got used about a year ago, but have already put several miles on.

I topped off the coolant and drove it around the block a few times, until I too started noticing some coming from the driver's side. I couldn't quite smell anything (I smoke too much), but the liquid was a pinkish color and it looks as if the coolant is about half-gone.

I read that the white smoke is likely a coolant leak, but when I opened up the hood it look as if the leak must have been spraying straight upwards and then dripping back down -- and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Trying to determine whether to bring it in, or if it's the radiator, possibly replace it myself. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly it could be any part of the system. You need to refill and pressure test it. A common failure point on these, are the plastic Y pipes that are  used to supply the front and rear heater cores. It comes off the backside of the thermostat housing.

Comment: Automatic transmission fluid will smoke white when burned. If you are seeing "pinkish" colored liquid, I'd suggest you look closer at the tranny and associated parts (to include cooling lines and radiator).

Comment: If you are located in the United States, Autozone just added these really nice coolant system pressure testers in their free tool loaner program. Easy way to safely find leaks.

Comment: Could it be the Y hose going to the heater? It's above the biggest leak of coolant, and it absolutely caked.

[Updated pic from FB Messenger](http://imgur.com/a/LbISo)

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture. The overlay and lack of lighting makes it hard to see. I'd grab a flashlight clean off the connectors at the y pipe and visually inspect them for cracks. As was mentioned you can rent a cooling system pressure tester for "free" and it will lead you to where the leak is exactly. This is a very common failure point and the dealers almost always have these in stock.

Comment: Start it up, drive it around the block until you get some smoke and then pop the hood while its running and see if you can locate the leak.  Or as everyone else said have it pressure tested to find the leak.